# polymer core-ajax post request status pending

Tags: ajax, polymer, web-component

I´m trying to update a mondodb document using expressjs as webservice. When I try to do the post request in polymer I get a 4 minutes pending status until "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE " shows. I tried using POSTMAN extension in chrome passing this raw body : `{"nombre":"Cecilia","ubicacion":"A Coruña"}` and it works. Any clue whats going on? Here the polymer code.

```
<core-ajax id="ajaxUpdate"
  auto
  method="post"
  url="{{urlUpdate}}"
  body='{"nombre":"{{info.nombre}}","ubicacion":"{{info.ubicacion}}"}'
  contentType = 'application/json'>
</core-ajax>
```

Comment: Check with Chrome Dev Tools if the body is correct. You could also try to remove the `contentType` and see if the server handles the default contentType ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

Comment: thanks for your response, it was a problem with the bodyParser inside the expressjs webservice. Had to parse it manually.